# Appending Binary to String in Python 3 (HTTP Response)

Tags: html, http, server, python-3.6

I'm current writing a small implementation of a HTTP server in Python.  When generating my request message, however, I'm encountering an issue where the binary contents of a file are not properly appending to my OK response message.

Here is the pre-formatted okay response:

```
OK = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK{} Content-Type:{}{}{}".format(CRLF, contentType, 
CRLF, CRLF)
```

When the server receives a request for some resource (in this case a html file, image, or mp3), it parses the request and pulls out the name of said resource.  Particularly, I'm having trouble with this function:

```
def getContents(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()
```

Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "myServer.py", line 46, in processRequest
    response = getRequest(request)
  File "myServer.py", line 82, in getRequest
    return OK + getContents(resource)
  File "myServer.py", line 136, in getContents
    return OK + f.read()
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

In other implementations, I've seen this operation (namely, OK + *read binary contents of file*) work before, but I'm a bit confused as to where to proceed from here.

Here is the entirety of the source code for those interested (please keep in mind this is an intentionally elementary implementation):

```
import sys, threading, os, socket, stat
from socket import *

contentType = None
CRLF = "\r\n"
METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED = "HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED{}Allow: GET, HEAD, POST {}Connection: close{}{}".format(CRLF, CRLF, CRLF, CRLF)
OK = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK{} Content-Type:{}{}{}".format(CRLF, contentType, CRLF, CRLF)
NOT_FOUND = 'HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND{}Connection: close{}{}'.format(CRLF, CRLF, CRLF)
FORBIDDEN = 'HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN{}Connection: close{}{}'.format(CRLF, CRLF, CRLF)
MOVED_PERMANENTLY = 'HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY{}Location:  *redacted*{}Connection: close{}{}'.format(CRLF, CRLF, CRLF, CRLF)
contentType = None

def main():
    if (len(sys.argv) == 1):
        port = 9001
    else:
        if (len(sys.argv) == 2):
            port = int(sys.argv[1])
        elif (len(sys.argv) > 2):
            print("Invalid number of arguments; Port number defaulted to 9001...\n")
            port = 9001
    host = "localhost"

    #creates socket object; SOCK_STREAM for TCP
    serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    #bind socket to host on specified port
    serverSock.bind((host, port))
    #listen on the socket with the maximum number of queued client connections set to 128
    serverSock.listen(128)

    print("Server is listening...\n")

    while 1:
        #block until a client connects to the designated local port
        connectionSock, addr = serverSock.accept()
        print("Client connection accepted; starting server thread...\n")
        server = threading.Thread(target=processRequest, args=[connectionSock, addr[0]])
        server.start()

def processRequest(connectionSock, srcAddress):
    request = connectionSock.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
    print("######\nREQUEST:\n{}\n######".format(request))
    method = ((request[0:4]).strip()).upper()

    if method == "GET":
        response = getRequest(request)
    elif method == "POST":
        response = postRequest(request)
    elif method == "HEAD":
        response = headRequest(request)
    else:
        response = METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED

    connectionSock.send(bytes(response, "utf-8"))
    connectionSock.shutdown(1)
    connectionSock.close()

def headRequest(request):
    resource = getResource(request)
    path = os.path.join(".", resource)
    if resource == *redacted*: 
        return MOVED_PERMANENTLY
    elif not os.path.exists(resource):
        return NOT_FOUND
    elif not checkPerms(resource):
        return FORBIDDEN
    else:
        getContentType(resource)
        return OK

def getRequest(request):
    headResponse = headRequest(request)
    if headResponse == MOVED_PERMANENTLY:
        return MOVED_PERMANENTLY + *redacted*
    elif headResponse == NOT_FOUND:
        return NOT_FOUND + getContents("404.html")
    elif headResponse == FORBIDDEN:
        return FORBIDDEN + getContents("403.html")
    else:
        resource = getResource(request)
        getContentType(resource)
        return OK + getContents(resource)

def postRequest(request):
    linelist = request.strip().split(CRLF)
    formInputs = linelist[-1].split("&")
    eventname = formInputs[0][10:]
    location = formInputs[1][9:]
    starttime = (formInputs[2][10:]).replace("%3A", ":")
    endtime = (formInputs[3][8:]).replace("%3A", ":")
    day = formInputs[4][4:]
    responseHTML = """
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Form Submission</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Following Form Data Submitted Successfully</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>eventname</td>
                    <td>{}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>starttime</td>
                    <td type=time>{}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>endtime</td>
                    <td type=time>{}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>location</td>
                    <td>{}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>day</td>
                    <td>{}</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
            </html>
                """.format(eventname, starttime, endtime, location, day)
    response = OK + responseHTML
    return response

def getResource(request):
    linelist = request.strip().split(CRLF)
    reqline = linelist[0]
    rlwords = reqline.split()
    return rlwords[1][1:]

def getContents(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()

def checkPerms(resource):
    """Returns True if resource has read permissions set on 'others'"""
    stmode = os.stat(resource).st_mode
    return (getattr(stat, 'S_IROTH') & stmode) > 0

def getContentType(resource):
    splitResource = resource.split(".")
    fileType = splitResource[1]
    if fileType == "png" or fileType == "jpg":
        contentType = "image/" + fileType
    elif fileType == "mp3":
        contentType = "audio/mpeg"
    elif fileType == "css":
        contentType = "text/css"
    else:
        contentType = "text/html"
    return

main()
```

Since many of the resources are simple html files, I was doing a read instead of a binary read before and then appending the string to OK.  However, this did not work for images or mp3 files for obvious reason.  I'm relatively new here, so please excuse any failure to follow proper etiquette (and be sure to point out said failures as well!). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```html
def processRequest(connectionSock, srcAddress):
    request = connectionSock.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
    print("######\nREQUEST:\n{}\n######".format(request))
    method = ((request[0:4]).strip()).upper()

    if method == "GET":
        response = getRequest(request)
    elif method == "POST":
        response = postRequest(request)
    elif method == "HEAD":
        response = headRequest(request)
    else:
        response = METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
        
    connectionSock.send(bytes(response, "utf-8"))
    connectionSock.shutdown(1)
    connectionSock.close()
```

Try using connectionSock.send(bytes(response)). I sometimes experience bugs like those above when adding the extra encoding for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds close enough to the socket programming assignment from Computer Networking: Top-down Approach. lol

The idea is that once the TCP connection has been set up, the server can send data into the TCP connection more than once. In other words, you don't have to append the bytes data with the HTTP OK message, and instead can do something like:

```
    # First return the HTTP OK message to client
    http_response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
    connectionSocket.send(http_response.encode())

    # Now you start transferring HTTP response body
    with open('.' + object_path, "rb") as file:
        data = file.read()
        connectionSocket.send(data)
        connectionSocket.close()
```

On the client-side, you should know how to first read the HTTP message and then deal with the bytes code in response body.